# Want a cell to equal 1 of 3 values based on if another cell falls within 3 different ranges

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula

What I want to do seems simple...but, I just cannot seem to find the correct function.I am sure this is easy for the folks on here!

I want a formula that does the following:

For Example:

> 1. When the cell value is equal to or greater than 1 or less than or equal to 3, the function cell should return a value of 35
> 2. When the cell value is greater than 3 or less than 6, the function cell should return a value of 30
> 3. When the cell value is equal to or greater than 6, the function cell should return a value of 25

That's it. I have been trying IF functions and combining AND functions but keep hitting errors.

Comment: 35 every time? Why?

Comment: Can  you post an example of an IF function you've tried?

Comment: Your question seems wrong, but try using Vlookup with TRUE as the last criteria to avoid a messy nested IF function. http://www.excelfunctions.net/Vlookup-Example-Closest-Match.html

Comment: Do you have negative cell values?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=INDEX({35,30,25},MATCH(MAX(A1,0),{0,4,6},1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Covers negatives:

```
=5*(5+(A1<6)+(A1<4))
```

or not (returns `10` for less than `1` and `25` for more than `6`):

```
 =5*(5*(A1>=1)+(A1<6)+(A1<4))
```

Comment: Different way to think about it, nice. (also updated mine to accept negatives!)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using or instead of and. For example *value is equal to **OR** greater than 1 or less than or equal to 3* should be *value is equal to or greater than 1 **AND** less than or equal to 3*? You also have to somehow detect if the value is less than 1. Right? Try below

```
=IF(A1<1,"Data < 1!",IF(AND(A1>=1,A1<=3),35,IF(AND(A1>3,A1<6),30,25)))
```

Comment: Several nested `IF`'s are typically considered bad practice because they are long, inefficient, and easy to mess up. Usually `MATCH` or `CHOOSE` or some other clever solution can be used in these cases. I recommend checking out the other answers here, as they provide better alternatives than nested `IF`'s.

Comment: Also, `AND` is unnecessary to use here, even if you have nested `IF`'s. For example, you could have this formula: `= IF(A1>=6,25,IF(A1>3,30,IF(A1>=1,35,"less than 1")))`